# Loop going through incorrectly in C++

Tags: c++, loops

So I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double balance = 0, withdraw = 0, deposit = 0;
string choice, quitOrNo;

class Bank
{
    public:
        void withdrawMoney()
        {
            if(balance - withdraw >= 0)
            {
                balance = balance - withdraw;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "$5 penalty for attempting to withdraw more than you have.";
                balance -= 5;
            }
        }
    public:
        void depositMoney()
        {
            balance = balance + deposit;
        }
};
int main()
{
    Bank bankObject;
    cout << "Welcome to the Bank Program!" << endl;
    while(true)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            cout << "Would you like to make a withdrawal, a deposit, or quit the program: ";
            cin >> choice;
            if(choice.compare("withdrawal") == 0 || choice.compare("w") == 0)
            {
                cout << "Please enter the amount to withdraw: ";
                cin >> withdraw;
                bankObject.withdrawMoney();
                cout << "New balance is: $" << balance << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(choice.compare("deposit") == 0 || choice.compare("d") == 0)
            {
                cout << "Please enter the amount to deposit: ";
                cin >> deposit;
                bankObject.depositMoney();
                cout << "New balance is: $" << balance << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(choice.compare("quit") == 0 || choice.compare("q") == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(choice.compare("quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Would you like to try again or quit: ";
        cin >> quitOrNo;
        if(quitOrNo.compare("quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Thank you for using the Bank Program." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the code, I get this output: 
--> Welcome to the Bank Program! Would you like to make a withdrawal, a deposit, or quit the program: **deposit** Please enter the amount to deposit: **100** New balance is: $100 Would you like to try again or quit: **try again** Would you like to make a withdrawal, a deposit, or quit the program: *Invalid input.* Would you like to try again or quit: <-- It will continue doing this until I just exit the program. Anyone know why? The **bold** text is the input from me and the *italicized* text is the input the computer gave itself. Everything in arrows is the console text.

Comment: When you get "Invalid Input", why don't you output the value of `choice` so you can figure out why.

Comment: No he has breaks in there. It looks like cin >> choice doesn't work properly the next time round.

Comment: @NeilKirk yeah I should probably read the whole post before I comment in the future.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, you can compare strings with ==.
if (choice == "deposit")
Also why are you using so many globals? Choice can be local to the main function. balance should be a member of your bank class. withdraw and deposit should be passed as function parameters.

Comment: Have you tried printing "quitOrNo"?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. @NeilKirk, yes that is what's happening. cin would not work the second time around, but only because I was trying to input two words. Also, I was only using .compare because I thought you had to. Coming from java, == doesn't work with strings. I'm brand new to this, (literally started learning today), so I'm still learning the ropes of this language.

Comment: If you are reading user input, it is a good idea to use `std::getline` to read a single line of input into a `std::string`. Only then, in order to further process that line, should you construct a `std::istringstream`, which can be used with `operator >>`, `.peek()`, `.read()`, etc. as if it were `std::cin`.

Comment: If the left variable is std::string, you can use ==. If the left (or both) are text literals, you must cast it to std::string. For example, string("mytext") == "myothertext" is correct but "mytext" == "myothertext" does not work. Welcome to C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try again` is two words but `>>` applied to a `std::string` only extracts one word. The `again` gets extracted by the next loop iteration. Use `getline` to extract exactly one line of input.

I'm not sure if or how it's going into an endless loop, but if `cin` can't process some input it's been given, it will stop accepting any more input until you call `cin.clear()`. In the meantime a statement `if (cin)` will see `cin` evaluate to `false`. A program lacking such a check will usually read infinite invalid input by default.

Comment: Thanks, it was just me typing in try again as an input like you said. If you only type one word the program works as expected. Sorry, I didn't even think of that when I made the program.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're reading a string, rather than a whole line.  String input is delimited by whitespace, not by end of line.

Because you typed `try again`, the value read into `quitOrNo` will be `try`, leaving the text `again` in the stream.  When you loop around and read into `choice`, you will get `again` which is invalid.  Because you keep typing the same thing, you keep getting the same problem.

You should look into using `std::getline` instead.